# Data migration among multiple databases with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I am trying to make an application where data will be migrated from one database to another database (Multiple dbs will be used). User can select the table at runtime & push it to target db. I am using spring-boot, spring data JPA & trying with Flyway. 
My issue is how to read the complete schema from source db as user can select the source db at runtime?

Sumit

Comment: so, you have complete architecture ready..?? but, you are stuck at *how to read the complete schema from source db as user can select the source db at runtime*

Comment: Its a POC which i m trying.... i didn't mention i have complete architecture ready

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a `MetaData` object from a JDBC connection and use it to obtain all kinds of information about the database, e.g. the list of tables.

See the following example which I took from [a tutorial](https://www.progress.com/blogs/jdbc-tutorial-extracting-database-metadata-via-jdbc-driver).

```
databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});

System.out.println("Printing TABLE_TYPE \"TABLE\" ");
System.out.println("----------------------------------");

while(resultSet.next())
{
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
}
```

*Note: JPA is most likely not the right tool for the job. Consider using Springs `JdbcTemplate` instead.*